# i am working with c# DateTime and i need to get the .Hour property in it's 24 hour format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

The If statement checking the hour always has a problem because my database returns a 24 hour format which returns false when 12pm <= 1pm.
here is the code:

```
public void SkippedDailyTask()
        {
            var pendingtasks = GetPendingTasks();
            if (pendingtasks.Count() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Empty List");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in pendingtasks)
                {
                    if (item.EndTime.Hour <= DateTime.Now.Hour)
                    {
                        if (item.EndTime.Minute <= DateTime.Now.Minute)
                        {
                            item.StatusReturner = StatusReturner.Skipped;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Empty List");
                        }
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: can you explain more your question not clear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The `Hour` property is just a value of 0-23. It's not in a format - it's an integer. I don't know what you mean by "which returns false when 12pm <= 1pm" . But I would strongly advise you to only evaluate `DateTime.Now` *once* so you can be consistent across all uses within the method. (It's also not clear that you should really be saving the changes every time you save any item, or that the message of "empty list" is appropriate for a *single item* not being in the past.)

Comment: As @JonSkeet mentioned, you cannot just compare hours, you need to compare the DateTime.

Answer (score -1):

`DateTime.Hour` always returns the hour value in 24hr format as an integer. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.hour?view=netframework-4.8

So if your `item.EndTime.Hour` returns 12 for 12:00PM and the current time is 1:00PM, the `if (item.EndTime.Hour <= DateTime.Now.Hour)` condition should return true as `DateTime.Now.Hour` will equal 13.

Also, not related to your question but, you are checking the count of `pendingTasks` using `pendingtasks.Count()`. In C#, `length/count` of iterables are implemented as properties rather than methods.

Answer (score -3):

```
public void SkippedDailyTask()
{
    var pendingtasks = GetPendingTasks();
    if (pendingtasks.Count() == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Empty List");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in pendingtasks)
        {
            var hourNow = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH"));
            // var hourItem = item.EndTime.Hour;
            var hourItem = Convert.ToInt32(item.EndTime.ToString("HH"));
            if (hourItem <= hourNow)
            {
                if (item.EndTime.Minute <= DateTime.Now.Minute)
                {
                    item.StatusReturner = StatusReturner.Skipped;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Empty List");
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: To help understanding try to use that code: 
**Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));**